# An error in creating a group by Python-list

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a Python code, in which I desire to group the values by their corresponding labels

```py
labels = [0, 0, 0,  1, 1,  2]
values = [1, 3, 5,  6, 7,  8]    

groups = [[]]*3

for i in range(len(values)): 
    groups[labels[i]] += [values[i]]

print(groups)
```

I expect to get

```
[[1,3,5], [6,7], [8]]
```

But, what I get from the code is

```
[[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

So, what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Indeed, the problem is fixed by replacing `groups = [[], [], []]`

Comment: `groups = [[]]*3` That creates three references to the _same_ list object.